# R Lattice: Removing the wireframe mesh

Tags: r, lattice, wireframe

I am currently trying to construct a simple `wireframe` plot from the `lattice` package, but consisting of several hundred points along the y axis. This leads to the plot being swamped by the wireframe mesh and all you see is a black mass. I know I can remove them altogether with `col=FALSE` but is there a way to limit the number of lines in the mesh from the y axis so the `drape=TRUE` colours can be seen?

```
levelplot(my.data, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "x", drape = TRUE, screen=list(z=0, x=-70, y=0), aspect = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A relatively old question, but as I've found a simple solution that helped with a similar problem, maybe this can also help others.

Simply reduce the line width:

```
wireframe(V3 ~ V1 + V2, data=mydata, drape=TRUE, lwd=0.2)
```

Best regards,
Alex